# How to pass a list (comma separated) to a traffic variable in Omniture?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a field "taxonomy" and I would like to pass it to Omniture. This Taxonomy field can have multiple values and I would like to calculate the count for each of the taxonomy separately. Let me explain my question with an example:

Item can be associated with multiple taxonomy. Letz say we are talking about an item called "Item1". This item can be associated with taxonomy "Tx1","Tx2","Tx3".

So the js code will be like,

```
s.prop1 = "Item1"
s.prop2 = "Tx1, Tx2, Tx3"
```

I was expecting omniture to store individual buckets/counters for "Tx1" "Tx2" and "Tx3". But Omniture created one bucket for "Tx1, Tx2, Tx3". I hope there is a way to treat them separately. Ideally I would not like to pass the taxonomies separately in separate prop variables.

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Rag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omniture does have the functionality you're looking for from version 15 onwards. Unfortunately it won't do it in a prop. You need to use a slightly different variable type. The variable you're looking for is a list eVar.

Every implementation has three of these available:

1. s.list1
2. s.list2
3. s.list3

[Here's the blog post where Omniture introduced them.](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/15-for-15-your-kiss-is-on-my-list-var/)
You can also find information on them in Knowledge Base article 10549 from inside the Adobe Marketing Cloud interface.

Comment: Thanks Racheet. I am going to try sending the taxonomies in list evar and I will update this section on the results. It looks like I will need to contact their customer care to get this set up. <<http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#List_Variable>>

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  As Crayon Violent mentions, there are both list props and list eVars.  Typically, what you want a list prop, as list eVars have some very important implications to attribution.  If you don't understand the difference between the two variable types, you should learn -- it's core to understanding how to properly implement Adobe Analytics (sitecat).  Simply setting all props and evars to everything is inefficient and usually unnecessary.  Crayon Violent's answer is the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 4):

Actually Omniture does support list-style props, aptly called a list prop.  You have to talk to Client Care to enable it for your prop, and you will need to specify a delimiter to use (like the comma). Then you would populate it exactly as you are doing, except without the space between the comma and value. ("a,b,c" not "a, b, c").

An alternative is the list eVar as Racheet mentioned.  The difference is that a list prop sends in values and each value is within a prop variable scope, vs. the list eVar values are recorded with an eVar scope.

If you decide to do it w/ a list eVar instead of list prop, read up on how Omniture handles the allocation for them..there are some implications to consider with them only being able to be set to first or last allocation...